# Passing property dynamically to react component doesn't recognized by karma test

Tags: reactjs, karma-runner, chai, enzyme

I'm trying to test whether a property that pass to a react component get the correct value, but it doesn't seems to work because (I think) the property get it's value dynamically depends on the parent component state. Here's the code (summarized):

```
import React from 'react';
import InfiniteScroll from 'react-infinite-scroller';

class myClass extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      ....
      inputChanged: 0
      ....
  };

  ...

  render() {
    let items = [];

  ... code that retrieve items ...


    return (
        <InfiniteScroll
          pageStart={this.state.inputChanged ? 1 : 0} // page start is changed according to this.state.inputChanged value
          loadMore={this.loadMore.bind(this)}
          hasMore={this.state.hasMoreItems}
          loader={<div className="loader" key={0}>Loading ...</div>}
          threshold={200}
        >
          <div className="container-fluid">
            <div className="row">
              {items}
            </div>
          </div>
        </InfiniteScroll>
    );
  }
}
```

And in my spec file:

```
import React from 'react';
import {mount} from 'enzyme';
import {expect} from 'chai';

describe('myClass', () => {
    let wrapper;

      beforeEach(() => {
        wrapper = mount(
          <myClass/>,
          {attachTo: document.createElement('div')}
        );
      });

    it('set correct pageStart', done => {
        const InfiniteScroll = wrapper.find('InfiniteScroll');
        wrapper.setState({
          inputChanged: 1
        });
        expect(InfiniteScroll.props().pageStart).to.equal(1);
        done();
      });
}
```

But no matter what, `InfinteScroll.props().pageStart` is 0 and the test fails.
As far as I understand, it should changed accounring to `wrapper.state().inputChanged`, but it doesn't. Any ideas why?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are holding on to the reference of `InfiniteScroll` before calling `setState`. You need to move the code to get the reference of `InfiniteScroll` after the `setState`. Here is the updated test.

```
it('set correct pageStart', done => {
    wrapper.setState({
        inputChanged: 1
    });
    const InfiniteScroll = wrapper.find('InfiniteScroll');
    expect(InfiniteScroll.props().pageStart).to.equal(1);
    done();
});
```